# Is there any way to connect to Yellowbrick database in Azure Data Factory

Tags: postgresql, azure-data-factory, yellowbrick

I wanted to connect to Yellowbrick(YB) database (Postgresql) as a source in the Azure Data Factory. The YB instance is on the cloud. And I had set the encryption to 'No Encryption'. In the server name, if I pass the domain name, then the error I get is "Socket closed." If I pass IP address, the error I get is "Verify hostname and port number."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. So my Yellowbrick database is an on-prem database. So, all I did is created a Self-Hosted Integration-Runtime for my database location and then used it in the data factory and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Good day sir!

To tell you the truth that I never met your problem, but I google 'Verify hostname and port number', and got some message that I thought may do some help.

Here is the link:https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/9334

Wish you to solve your problem soon.